# Should I use events or function binding in angular for components to talk to each other

Tags: angularjs

Which is recommended :

Parent template:

```
<parent>
 <child-component "doSomethingFunction = $ctrl.referrencedDoSomethingFunction()">
</parent>
```

Child component:

```
child_component = {
                controller: childController,
                require: {
                    parentCtrl: '^^parentComponentCtrl'
                },
                bindings: {
                    doSomethingFunction: '&',
                },
                template:childTemplate
            };
```

OR

```
<parent>
 <child-component>
</parent>
```

Parent controller:

```
$scope.$on('somethingHappened',  function (event, data) {
                //doSomething now..
            });)
```

Child controller:

```
  $scope.$emit('somethingHappened')
```

Not sure if one is better than the other , one reason I think function binding might be better is that it gives a API in form of binding so the user of the component might know what is need before he uses the component.

But is one way recommended than the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In general prefer function binding. Components with clear input and output are easy to read and use.
2. When this leads to lots of extra code - when you want pass something from very bottom component to parent like 3-4 leves, you may consider using events. But this is quite rare case.

Comment: makes sense ,just waiting a bit if anyone else has any additional input before marking this as answer .